# How many combinations are possible?

Tags: combinatorics

I have 12 objects of 3 different types: 5 type A, 4 type B, and 3 type C. These objects must be arranged into 6 pairs such that no type is paired with another of the same type.

The only arrangement I can come up with is:
Three A/B, Two A/C, One B/C

There might not be another way; however, I'm surprised I can't come up with another arrangement.

Excluding reshuffling which individual of a type is paired with whatever other individual--that is, on a strictly type by type rather than individual basis--are any other arrangements possible?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to convince yourself no other arrangements are possible, imagine you're going to seat the pairs at $6$ separate tables, each table with just two chairs.  (In restaurant parlance, such a table is called a two-top.)  The $5$ A's must each sit separately, so start by seating them at separate tables.  This leaves one empty table, which can only seat a BC pair (since the A's have already been seated).  Filling the sixth table with a BC pair leaves $3$ B's and $2$ C's, which must be seated with the A's.